# Python for loop only saves the last loop in my 2-d array

Tags: python, arrays, loops, for-loop, random-walk

I am producing one dimensional random walks and I want my for loop to save the maximum distance from the origin that has been reached so far, as time progresses. 5 random walks are produced.
This is my code:

```
for j in range(5):
    r = rand(10000)
    t = range(10000)
    x = zeros(10000)
    y = zeros((10000, 5))
    for i in range(10000):
        walk = r[i]
        if walk < 0.5:
            x[i] = x[i-1] - 1
            y[:,j]= maximum.accumulate(abs(x))
        else:
            x[i] = x[i-1] + 1
            y[:,j]= maximum.accumulate(abs(x))
    plot(t,x, label="Walk %d" %(j+1))

title("1-D Random Walk (Position versus Time)")
xlabel("Time")
ylabel("Position")
legend(loc="best")
grid()
```

The problem is that after the for loop iterates over the set range (5) the output 2-d array only includes the last iteration.
Somehow, it overwhites the previous ones, so I would only get a 10000x5 array with only the last row filled in.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've, for some reason, chosen to execute

```
y = zeros((10000, 5))
```

over and over again, each time through the outer loop.

As an obvious consequence, only the last assignment to `y` can possibly "take", evidently overriding any previous assignment to the same name.  What other behavior could you possibly expect from such repeated assignments?!

Move this assignment **outside** the outer loop, and there will be no "overriding" of the name `y`.

Comment: THANK YOU!
I was trying to figure out where my mistake was since yesterday. I couldn't see it in front of my eyes.
Again thanks.